# SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR not working on API 28

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-navigation-bar

I have a problem with `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR` somehow not working, but `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` is working. I'm working with Android API 28 at the moment.

So whats happening? On API 23 and below I get translucent Status Bar and Navigation Bar as expected. Between API 23 and API API 26 I get transculent Navigation Bar and Light Mode Status bar as expected. But on API 27 and above I get the Light Mode Status Bar but not the Light Mode Navigation Bar. It just is the normal black one and nothing changes.

Here is my MainActivity with my code to enable Translucent or Light Mode Status Bar and Navigation Bar based on the Android API Level (Note my comments describe what works and what doesn't):

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
Window win = getWindow();

//Setup Status Bar and Nav Bar white if supported
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);// <- works not
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR); // <- works
}
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 27) {
    //this here works
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
} else {
    //this here works
    win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
}
```

And this here is my style.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Can you guys tell me what's missing? I use the exact same code for Navigation bar as I do for the Status Bar but only the Status Bar gets Light Mode. Thanks for every help

Comment: Note: SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR was added in API level 26. Not 27. BTW it is deprecated since API level 30. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After hours of testing I figured it out! First you have to set your Navigation Bar to white in xml with target API above 26 in your style.xml:

```
 <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="27">@android:color/white</item>
```

After that you have to import this flag in your Main Activity:

```
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS;
```

And in your Code you have to set the flags all toghether like this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS | 
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR |
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
}
```

And now if Im above API 26 I get Light Nav and Status Bar!

Answer (score 3):

In your code `NAVIGATION_BAR` flag is getting override by `STATUS_BAR` Flag.

To add both the flag replace.

```
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

With

```
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

Update:
You can also specify the Color of the NavigationBar

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary));
```

Comment: did what you said but somehow no the navigation bar is just black. No buttons displayed, but the navigation bar still works for example if I click in the middle to return to homescreen.

Comment: Also, You need to Set NavBar Color